# Post List of New Objects Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to limit the number of calls to a rails API. I want to be able to send a list of objects to this endpoint rather than call the api once per object. I have the following relation:

`Parent`: -> has_and_belongs_to_many `Children`

`Child`: -> has_and_belongs_to_many `Parents`, requires a `parent`, and requires a `hobby`

`Hobby`: -> `hobby_name`, `rank`:int

Lets say I wanted to have an endpoint `/parents/:id/children`. How would I pass a list of children/hobbies in and create either all of them (or none) managing the has_and_belongs_to_many and the nested attributes. I'm not seeing how to link the children to their parent when doing a `Child.create([{attrs}])`.

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work in rails console?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example json:

```
# POST parent/1/children
{
  children: [
    {
      attr1: 1,
      attr2: 2,
      ...
    },
    {
      attr1: 1,
      attr2: 2,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

It could be achieve by a loop like this:

```
parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
params[:children].each do |child_params|
  parent.children.create(child_params)
end
```